# BitArray high performance Or & And & Xor

Tags: c#, bitarray

Here is examle of usage:

```
bitarray = bitarray.And(mask);
```

And question is how efficient it is compare to same operation on `int[]` with copy to that same array but not creating another one and return it (what cost time and creating useless garbage)
I know already what BitArray type has private non-public member `m_array` and it is simply `int[]`.
Is there some method to make this operations without creating new instances? For example like this:

```
bitarray.And(mask);
```

And simplier, I want to fasten this operation

```
bitarray |= mask;
```

And I would know what instance bitarray changed inside without creating new instance of `BitArray`.

I know, I can do that with reflection but I don't think it will be faster...
Or is there some better approach than creating my own `BitArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How efficient compared to your own int[] implementation? Write tests and find out.

BitArray is not immutable, it does not create copies. It simply returns the same instance. It would seem to me that your own implementation wouldn't really beat it.

See BitArray: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/bitarray.cs,0a9d097e057af932,references

Comment: Oh, i dint know that. This operation returns same instance...a little bit strange though....for what purpose?

Comment: @eocron: The pattern is known as "fluent interface", which means it allows you to chain calls, so you can have .And(mymask).Or(otherMask).Xor(thirdMask); which can be quite convenient. The second reason is most likely performance: if it would create new BitArray each time, it would be so slow.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some method to make this operations without creating new instances?

The `BitArray.And()` method doesn't return a new instance of `BitArray`. It just returns the "current" instance (i.e. the instance you used when you called the method).

> And I would know what instance bitarray changed inside without creating new instance of `BitArray`

It seems to me that the most straight-forward way of accomplishing that would be to simply write a loop that compares the bit values in the `bitarray` object with those in the `mask` object *before* you apply the `And()` method.

Note that to do anything interesting with this information, you probably need to save it in some data structure somewhere. So frankly, I don't see much advantage in trying to avoid creating a new `BitArray` object for the purpose.